# Node.js parallel file download, the ES6 way

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, http, web-scraping, ecmascript-6

I wrote a script that downloads all PDFs found on the web page of a particular government agency. I would have chosen `bash` for such a task, but I want the script to run in Node.js. The downloaded files are a few hundred kilobytes big, if that matters.

It is the first time I use ES6, but I want to learn how to take advantage of all ES6 features, and I want to make my script very much in the spirit of ES6. In bash I would have downloaded the list of PDF files first, then proceeded to download them with indentation back to zero, but I got the impression that putting everything within the first `request.get` block is more in the ES6 spirit, correct me if I am wrong.

The script works, and validates with [ESLint](http://eslint.org/demo/) after disabling the following rules:

- `no-console` because it is intended to be run on the console
- `no-undef` because it tells me `require is not defined`
- `one-var` because it would force me to mix require and other declaration thus triggering `no-mixed-requires`
- `sort-vars` because I want to order constants in a more sensible way
- `strict` because it would not accept `"use strict";` as the first line

My code:

```
"use strict";

// Imports
const async = require("async"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    http = require("http"),
    request = require("request");

// Settings
const INDEX_URL = "http://www.kokuminhogo.go.jp/hinan/index.html",
    MAX_PARALLEL_DOWNLOADS = 3,
    PREFECTURES_REGEX = /area.*hinan_(.*)\.pdf/g,
    REMOTE_PREFIX = "http://www.kokuminhogo.go.jp/pdf/hinan_",
    LOCAL_PREFIX = "data/file",
    FORMAT_EXTENSION = ".pdf",
    REGEX_MATCH_INDEX = 1,
    HTTP_STATUS_OK = 200;

// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Utility to download a file, with callback
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const download = (url, dest, next) => {

    console.log(`Downloading ${url} to ${dest}`);
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);

    http.get(url, (response) => {

        response.pipe(file);
        file.on("finish", () => {

            file.close();
            next();

        });

    });

};

// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Get list of available prefectures
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
request.get(INDEX_URL, (error, response, body) => {

    const prefectures = [];

    if (!error && response.statusCode === HTTP_STATUS_OK) {

        let match = PREFECTURES_REGEX.exec(body);

        while (match !== null) {

            prefectures.push(match[REGEX_MATCH_INDEX]);
            match = PREFECTURES_REGEX.exec(body);

        }

    }

    console.log(`Number of prefectures available: ${prefectures.length}`);

// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Download the PDF files for all prefectures
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Files will be numbered 1, 2, etc
    let fileNumber = 1;

    // Process in parallel
    async.eachLimit(
        prefectures,
        MAX_PARALLEL_DOWNLOADS,
        (prefecture, next) => {

            download(
                REMOTE_PREFIX + prefecture + FORMAT_EXTENSION,
                LOCAL_PREFIX + fileNumber + FORMAT_EXTENSION,
                next
            );
            fileNumber += 1;

        }

        ,
        () => {

            console.log("Finished downloading");

        }
    );

});
```

Comment: To get around having to use `no-undef`, tell ESLint it's being run in Node: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments

Answer (score 1):

Things that come to my mind after a quick read:

1. do not use `const someFunction = (...) => {...}` instead of `function someFunction(...) {...})`
2. use `module.exports` even if it is a script
3. group functionality into functions; you have comments beautifully spaced, but a function name will be more readable and maintainable
4. try to have functions that do one thing; when explaining to someone what a function does, and you have to use `and` then you should split the function
5. try to use `map`, `filter`, etc. instead of having iterations with a variable (e.g. `fileNumber`)
6. whenever you have `someString + someOther` you could use string templating (i.e. `${someString}${someOther}`
7. prefer using promises instead of callbacks; the code ends up being more readable; e.g. use [bluebird.promisify](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html)
8. use a good eslint config (e.g. [airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript))

To enhance collaboration, you could use a github repository and reference it here.